# Two phase commit rollback jboss 7.x testing (2pc)

Tags: jdbc, jms, rollback, transactional, xa

I am trying to test 2 pc transaction rollback on JBOSS eap7.
With xa jms setup and an oracle xa data source.

Bean doing an update on db using oracle xa data source and publishing a jms messg.
MDB receiving the message and throwing a run time exception.

I expected my db transaction to roll back as well but it is committed.

My session is in 
   Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);

Any ideas or better tests to check this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using annotations to mark your MDB as transactional.  For example:

```
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class myMDB implements MessageListener {
...
...
...
}
```

This will cause JBoss to start a transaction for all methods in the MDB.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I didn't realise that the container will always default to transacted.